# Как сделать выборку из БД, по значению ввода, в ajax?

Tags: php, javascript

Я в JS и ajax не силен, прошу помощи.
Задача: есть поле ввода input, и при изменение текста в нем, должен делаться новый запрос к базе данных, и выборка должна идти на основе введенного текста в поле, пытаюсь делать так:

```
    $('#street').on('input keyup', function(e) {
    var name_st = this.value;

    <?
    $sql_streetj = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `street` WHERE `name_ru` = 'ТУТ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ ИЗ name_st'"));


      $sl2 = array();
      $all_city_db2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `houses` WHERE `id_street` = '$sql_streetj[id]'");
      while ($city_name_ru2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_city_db2)) {
        $sl2[] = $city_name_ru2['name_ru'];
      }
    ?>

});
```

У меня не получается вставить значение переменной из JS: **name_st**, 
все должно происходить без перезагрузки страницы.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Ну так делайте запрос на сервер на котором php. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ p.s. и `<?` стоит писать как `<?php`

Comment: @Naumov вы извините, но я ничего не понял.  как  это можно совместить с моим кодом? у меня все на одной странице

Comment: код `var name_st = this.value;` выполняется на клиенте браузером, а код между `<? ... ?>` - на сервере.

Comment: @Igor может быть есть какие нибудь наглядные примеры? просто столько сидел за компьютером сегодня в поиске решения этой задачи, что возможно не вижу очевидного

Comment: Ладно начнём с основ. Сервер есть php код выполняеться?

Comment: @Naumov есть, выполняется

Comment: Уже лучше, смотрите вам надо в js сделать http запрос на ваш сервер с параметром и получив ответ уже на js распарсить его.

Answer (score 1):

В функции javascript-a вы не можете вызвать PHP!
Для этого используйте ajax, вам надо отправить значение полученное в JS на файл php который обработает ваш запрос и отправит ответ

JS

```
$('#street').on('input keyup', function(e) {
    var name_st = this.value;
    j.ajax( {
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'url обработчика php',
      data: {info:name_st},
      'success' : function (result) {
          console.log(result);  
      }
    });
 });
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['info'])){
          $sql_streetj = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `street` WHERE `name_ru` = '".$_POST['info']."' "));
          $sl2 = array();
          $all_city_db2 = mysql_query(
              "SELECT * FROM `houses` WHERE `id_street` = '$sql_streetj[id]'"
           );

          while ($city_name_ru2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_city_db2)) {
              $sl2[] = $city_name_ru2['name_ru'];
          }
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: минус за то что вы тоже не правильно написали код :D привидите его в порядок пожалуйста и изменю его.

Comment: я не виноват )) ваш редактор глючит! )

Comment: Да причём тут редактор я про ключевые моменты

Comment: не вносите изменения я сам поправлю всё

Comment: @Naumov сори но немогу с редактором договорится )) удаляет пол кода)) может я нето делаю ?

Comment: Вносите код после выделяете всё и на знак {} жмёте для форматирование либо { потом перенос строки и 4-ре пробела. так же закрываете код скобкой }, ` знак косой черты однострочный код.

Comment: p.s. воздерживайтесь от ответов вида вы не так пишите код так как это может задеть человека, а сообщество у нас довольно дружелюбное и конфликты не к чему.

Comment: я не хотел обидеть )) просто чтобы обратил внимание на критическую ошибку ))

Comment: @Naumov за инфу  {}  спс , а то замучался ))

Comment: Ну так вы тоже не без ошибок написали ) а так welcome.